# How to collect filtered stream array output as list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java8 syntax, How can we get the output as list after filtered.
In my case filter returns an array.

Added in comments, is there any better way can we get it

```
Config config = new Config("ooo", "wc", "code");
    Config config1 = new Config("ppp", "wc", "code");
    Config config2 = new Config("ooo", "wc", "code");

    Config[] configs = {config, config1, config2};

    Config config4 = new Config("ooo", "REG", "code");
    Config config5 = new Config("ppp", "REG", "code");
    Config config6 = new Config("ooo", "REG", "code");

    Config[] _configs = {config4, config5, config6};

    PromoCode promoCode = new PromoCode(121, "VOUCHER", "121", configs);
    PromoCode promoCode1 = new PromoCode(122, "VOUCHER", "122", null);
    PromoCode promoCode2 = new PromoCode(123, "LINK", "123", configs);
    PromoCode promoCode3 = new PromoCode(124, "VOUCHER", "124", null);
    PromoCode promoCode4 = new PromoCode(125, "LINK", "125", _configs);
    PromoCode promoCode5 = new PromoCode(126, "LINK", "126", _configs);

    List<String> resultantValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    PromoCode[] promoCodes = {promoCode, promoCode1, promoCode2, promoCode3, promoCode4, promoCode5};
    Stream<PromoCode> stream = Stream.of(promoCodes);
    stream.parallel()
        .filter(x -> x.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("VOUCHER"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .parallelStream()
        .forEach(x-> {
            Stream.of(x.getConfigs())
                .filter(t -> t.getOccasion().equals("wc"))
            //after filter, how can we get the output
             // List of list of strings format
                .forEach(o -> {
                    resultantValues.add(o.getProduct()+"_"+o.getProduct());
                });
        });

    System.out.println(resultantValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

to retrieve a `List<List<T>>` it can be done as follows:

```
 Stream.of(promoCodes)
       .parallel() // is this really needed?
       .filter(x -> x.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("VOUCHER"))          
       .map(x-> 
            Stream.of(x.getConfigs())
                .filter(t -> t.getOccasion().equals("wc"))
                .map(o ->  o.getProduct()+"_"+o.getProduct())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
       )
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you want a `List<T>` format then use `flatMap`:

```
 Stream.of(promoCodes)
       .parallel() // is this really needed?
       .filter(x -> x.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("VOUCHER"))          
       .flatMap(x-> 
            Stream.of(x.getConfigs())
                  .filter(t -> t.getOccasion().equals("wc"))
                  .map(o ->  o.getProduct()+"_"+o.getProduct())
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or as @Holger mentions, for the second approach you can avoid the nesting in the `flatMap` with:

```
 Stream.of(promoCodes)
       .parallel() // is this really needed?
       .filter(x -> x.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("VOUCHER"))
       .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.getConfigs()))
       .map(x -> x.getProduct() + "_" + x.getProduct())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which is definitely more readable:

---

Note that I've also removed some of the unnecessary method calls such as  the intermediate collecting to a list `.collect(Collectors.toList())` , `.parallelStream()` et al.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired results. First `filter` the promocodes with the given code VOUCHER. For each filtered promocode, you have an array of configs. We get that and flatten it to get a `stream` of `Config` objects. In the next step we filter out all the configs whose occasion is not equal to `wc`. Then we map all the matching `config` objects to get the desired result. At the final step we `collect` the result into a container.

```
final List<String> finalResult = Stream.of(promoCodes)
        .filter(pc -> pc.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("VOUCHER"))
        .flatMap(pc -> Stream.of(pc.getConfigs()))
        .filter(conf -> conf.getOccasion().equals("wc"))
        .map(conf -> conf.getProduct() + "_" + conf.getProduct())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```